# Detect Silverlight OOB install from Windows

Tags: silverlight-5.0

Is there a way to pragmatically detect that a Silverlight OOB application is installed on a computer from windows? (IE not the browser).  Possibly a registry path, or file path that can be checked?  I've got another application (nonSilverlight) that needs to open up a silverlight OOB application if it is installed or take them to the web page to install it if it is not installed.  The operating system will always be winXP or win7.

Comment: I'm working on a Silverlight OOB app, and have it installed locally.
I looked at the shortcut on the desktop, and went spelunking in the registry:

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a Silverlight OOB app, and have it installed locally.
I looked at the shortcut on the desktop, and went spelunking in the registry:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\348253213.demo.net]
>   "DisplayName"="DemoApp" "Comments"="DemoApp on your desktop; at home,
>   at work or on the go." "Publisher"="demo.net"
>   "InstallLocation"="C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\348253213.demo.net"
>   "NoRepair"=dword:00000001 "NoModify"=dword:00000001
>   "UninstallString"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Silverlight\5.1.20125.0\Silverlight.Configuration.exe -uninstallApp
>   348253213.demo.net"

No idea how the '348253213' got cooked up, but maybe this will give you some clues for ferreting out an installed SL app...

Comment: Under the OutOfBrowser dir there might be any number of subdirectories.  
Each subdir will have an application.xap.  You could inspect each one of those, looking for your app's particular dll.